# Apply extension function to several types at once in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, extension-function

Is it possible to apply an extensions function to several types at once?
Something link this

```
fun <Double || Float>.toString(): String
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. Anyway, it wouldn't be very useful, as you rarely can perform same operations with entirely different types.

Comment: The only way this works is, when all of the types share a common supertype. For example, you could add an extension function to `Number`. However, as pointed out by @broot, this might not prove very useful. The syntax you suggest looks a lot like union types, which might be supported in a [future version of Kotlin](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/union-types/77). If you're in control of the type hierarchy, you may want to look at `sealed interfaces / classes`, which is probably the closest you'll get to union types with the current version of Kotlin.